# Build my own version of graph.microsoft.io

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/ seems to be built on top of the Azure AD graph - https://graph.windows.net/

I haven't found a lot of how graph.microsoft.io was built, but it seems like it is a superset of the original Azure AD API, together with the stuff to access data from Office 365 through the graph.

What stands out to me is that either they would have passed through queries from graph.microsoft.io to graph.windows.net or they would have rebuilt it all from scratch. So, I'm trying to understand how to build my own such graph. I will use Azure AD, which will enable my authentication and authorization. It will give me a graph of the users in my organization. But for custom applications that also use Azure AD for login, I would like them to be available via the graph, like how the Office 365 apps are available via the graph.microsoft.io site.

So far, to implement something similar, it seems like I can use the core Azure AD graph for a specific set of user data, and for apps that use the Azure AD instance that I provide, I can require them to implement an Odata endpoint which describes how their own data can be accessed.

Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly pretty much exactly what we do, so who am I to argue.  However, rather than going to Azure AD directly for the graph of users in your org, I'd encourage you to go to MS Graph for that data, as we'll be looking to add richness and functionality there rather than in the underlying AAD Graph as time marches on, and also it will enable you to link across easily to other Office apps of course.

Over time, we'd like you not to have to do this, but rather to bring your own apps' data into the Microsoft Graph in some fashion, but we are a ways away from having that facility available.